# LDAP : Uploading LDIF

Tags: ldap, ldif

I am trying to upload entries to LDAP, but i keep getting error.
I have installed LDAP server in STS, and created my new partition as so :

```
name : messenger
id : o=messenger
cache=100
Auto generate Context Entry = unchecked
```

After starting the server and connecting, i try to upload the following ldif file :

```
dn: ou=roles, o=messenger
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit
ou: roles

dn: ou=people, o=messenger
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit
ou: people

dn: cn=USER, ou=roles, o=messenger
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: USER
member: uid=Lazaruss, cn=Bojan Milojkovic, ou=people, o=messenger
member: uid=Kale, cn=Davor Milojkovic, ou=people, o=messenger
member: uid=Jovana, cn=Jovana Pozek, ou=people, o=messenger

dn: cn=ADMIN, ou=roles, o=messenger
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: ADMIN
member: uid=Lazaruss, cn=Bojan Milojkovic, ou=people, o=messenger

dn: uid=Lazaruss, cn=Bojan Milojkovic, ou=people, o=messenger
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bojan Milojkovic
sn: Milojkovic
uid: Lazaruss
name: Bojan
userPassword: Welcome11

dn: uid=Kale, cn=Davor Milojkovic, ou=people, o=messenger
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Davor Milojkovic
sn: Milojkovic
uid: Kale
name: Davor
userPassword: Kale01

dn: uid=Koala, cn=Jovana Pozek, ou=people, o=messenger
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Jovana Pozek
sn: Pozek
uid: Koala
name: Jovana
userPassword: zrenjanin
```

But it keeps failing with error :

```
LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType :
ADD_REQUEST...

...
ERR_251_PARENT_NOT_FOUND Parent  cn=Bojan Milojkovic, ou=people,
o=messenger not found
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the entry for `cn=Bojan Milojkovic`before the entry for `uid=Lazaruss`. Or possibly you intend for these to be a single entry, in which case its RDN should be formed as `uid=Lazaruss+cn=Bojan Milojkovic`.